# Is there any module implicitly imported/loaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. When starting the interactive Python interpreter with default
   settings, is there any module implicitly imported/loaded into the
   interpreter, without explicitly running `import <modulename>`?

   I thought that modules like `sys` or `builtins` would be, but when I
   type their module names,

   ```
   >>> sys
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

   >>> builtins
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'builtins' is not defined
   ```

   So is it correct that by default, there is no module imported/loaded implicitly?
2. When executing a python script, is there any module implicitly
   imported/loaded into the script, without explicitly specifying
   `import <modulename>` in the script?

Thanks.

Comment: There may be, but **not in the global namespace**. Try `python -v`. Again, these modules are imported, and won't have to be "reloaded" when you actually write `import <module>`, but they won't be in the global namespace.

Comment: see `globals()` you'll find `__builtins__` and `__loader__`  which is [`<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter>`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter). Both are loaded by default.

Comment: @ChihebNexus Thanks. In python3, if module `builtins` is implicitly loaded by default, why isn't the name `builtins`  available  (see the output in my post)?

Comment: @Tim Well, it's a little bit tricky. I really think it's a shadow import. Actually `__builtins__` is imported by default not `builtins`. However if you look at `globals()` you'll see that `__builtins__` is imported by default. And `__builtins__.__dict__` will throw the same results as `builtins.__dict__` after importing `import builtins`. So, i think, correct me if i'm wrong, it's a shadow import in a default behaviour of the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One module that is usually imported automatically is site.py. And it imports a lot of other modules. But even if you prevent it from importing using option `-S` Python still imports many modules. Try the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7 -ESs

import sys
print(sys.modules)
```

and see how many modules are there. Change shebang to

```
#! /usr/bin/python3 -EISs
```

and say "Wow!" :-)

Comment: Thanks. Is `sys` itself loaded by default? I guess the way in your post can;t show that.

Comment: All modules listed in `sys.modules` are loaded but they aren't in module `builtins`, hence they aren't automatically available in the current namespace. You still have to import them.

Comment: Thanks. What modules are automatically available in the current namespace, i.e. without me importing them?

Answer (score 1):

Only __builtins__:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7 -ESs
print(dir())
```

=> ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']